# 404 error when trying to open Extent Report html file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I'm trying to get a simple Extent Report to work for my Selenium test.
I can run my test successfully, and the extent report html file is generated, but when I try to open it I get a 404 error.

At the moment for learning purposes I am just running the checkPageTitle method via my testng.xml file:

```
package wade.selenium;

import PageObjects.HomePage;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class HomePageTest extends BaseTest {

    public WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait w;
    private Logger l;
    ExtentReports extent;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void intializeTest(String browser) throws InterruptedException {
        l = LogManager.getLogger(HomePageTest.class.getName());
        driver = initializeDriver(browser);
        l.debug("Creating an explicit wait object");
        w = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    }

    @Test()
    public void checkPageTitle() {
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Takealot.com: Online Shopping | SA's leading online store");
    }

    @Test(enabled = false)
    public void checkAllLinks() throws InterruptedException {
        l.debug("Creating a TestNg soft assert object");
        SoftAssert a = new SoftAssert();
        l.debug("Retrieving HomePage object");
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        List<WebElement> allLinks = homePage.getAllLinks();
        int index = -1;
        for (WebElement link : allLinks) {
            index++;
            l.trace("Testing link " + (link.getText().equals("") ? link.getAttribute("href") : link.getText()));
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(link.getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                conn.connect();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode >= 400) {
                    l.error("Link with text " + link.getText()  + " with URL " + link.getAttribute("href")  + "is broken, response code = " + responseCode);
                }
                a.assertTrue(responseCode < 400);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                l.error("Link with text " + link.getText() + " at index " + index + "threw an exception: " + e.getMessage());
                a.assertTrue(false, "A link test threw an exception");
            }
        }
        a.assertAll();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void returnToLandingPage() {
        returnToLandingPage(driver);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        l.info("Quitting driver");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

My ExtentReports object is created via my ExtentReporterTool class:

```
package Tools;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;

public class ExtentReporterTool {

    static ExtentReports extent;

    public static ExtentReports getReportObject(){
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\Logs\\Extent_Report.html";
        ExtentSparkReporter reporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(path);
        reporter.config().setReportName("Automated Test Results");
        reporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Results");
        extent=new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(reporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Tester", "Wade Profe");
        return extent;
    }
}
```

And I am implementing the report in my testng Listeners class:

```
package wade.selenium;

import Tools.ExtentReporterTool;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Listeners implements ITestListener {

    Logger l = LogManager.getLogger(Listeners.class.getName());
    ExtentReports extent = ExtentReporterTool.getReportObject();
    ExtentTest test;

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        l.info("Starting test: " + result.getName() + " from " + result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getSimpleName());
        test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        l.info("Test " + result.getName() + " successfully executed in " + (result.getEndMillis() - result.getStartMillis()) + " milliseconds");
        test.log(Status.PASS, result.getName() + " Passed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.fail(result.getThrowable());
        l.fatal("Test " + result.getName() + " failed: " + result.getThrowable());
        WebDriver driver = null;
        try {
            driver = (WebDriver) result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getDeclaredField("driver").get(result.getInstance());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            l.fatal(e.getMessage());
        }
        l.trace("Creating a screenshot of the error page");
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\Logs\\Screenshots\\" +
                    result.getName() + " failure - [" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString().replace(":", "-") + "]" + ".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            l.fatal(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        l.info("Skipping " + result.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedWithTimeout(ITestResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        extent.flush();
    }
}
```

See below for what is happening when I try to open my html file:

[image]

Comment: I have same issue in mac. but i am able to open report from project folder. i don't know how to configure url in project.